# Como fazer URL Amigável

Tags: php, nginx, yii, url-amigável

Estou utilizando o `Framework` `Yii` e preciso criar `URLs` amigáveis.

Exemplo de URL: `http://meudominio.com/meuControle/minhaView`
Que é Equivalente à: `http://meudominio.com/index.php?r=meuControle/minhaView`

No `config/main.php` tenho habilitado:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

Porem quando tento acessar alguma página utilizando a URL Amigável, tenho o seguinte retorno:

> 404 Not Found
>
> nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Como faço para resolver esta situação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feita as alterações necessárias no `config/main.php`, será necessário alterar as configurações no servidor `Nginx`.

No arquivo `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` ou no arquivo do seu servidor na pasta `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` adicione:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

#Bloqueia o acesso direto às pastas do Yii
location ~ ^/(app|framework|themes/\w+/views){
    deny all;
}

#Bloqueia o acesso direto aos recursos estáticos
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

E por final, reinicie o serviço.

```
# service nginx restart
```

Para mais informações, [documentação em inglês](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/pt_br/quickstart.apache-nginx-config).