# Como gerar automaticamente e redirecionar o link no cabeçalho

Tags: php, javascript, aplicação-web

Eu estou precisando gerar um sistema onde possuo uma página template (o perfil do fb por exemplo) e que vai ser alimentada pelo meu banco de dados com as informações de acordo com o ID de um usuário.
O meu problema é: não quero que o link do parâmetro passado (id) seja exposto no cabeçalho da página e sim uma variável desse usuário que dei query (o usuario dele por exemplo) e que ao mesmo tempo se eu acessar esse link (www.meusite.com/usuario) ele seja redirecionado para essa mesma página (dando o query no BD e puxando as informações normalmente)

Isso é possivel via PHP ou JS?

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1):

É possível sim,

Para configurar a url da página veja esses links: 
[Como fazer URL Amigável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41956/) ou [Como faço url amigável no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112332/)

Para teste você pode pegar a url atual com `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

Com JS existe uma pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43814/obter-a-url-anterior-com-javascript) no StackOverflow sobre pegar url da página anterior

Com o valor dessa url você pode usar as funções `substr()` para pegar o valor após a "/" e enviar para o controle do seu sistema, lá você faz a consulta passando esse valor

Para enviar o `id` do usuário sem ser por `$_GET` você pode usar `$_SESSION` ou `$_POST`